# Telegram Bot: Custom Keyboard [Python]

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I've downloaded this [open-source code](https://github.com/yukuku/telebot) from GitHub which is written in Python(that I'm pretty new to it), I wanted to make my bot to have a Custom-Keyboard instead of letting users say whatever they wanted. for instance if user start the chat with my bot, they will automatically send `/start` and when this happens I want my bot to give them two to three options `['Option One'], [Option Two],` on keyboard, when they choose one of those options, I want to have totally  different options (for instance `['Plan A'], ['Plan B'],`). And again when they choose one of them, they get different options on their keyboard, and so on.

```
class WebhookHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def post(self):
    urlfetch.set_default_fetch_deadline(60)
    body = json.loads(self.request.body)
    logging.info('request body:')
    logging.info(body)
    self.response.write(json.dumps(body))

    update_id = body['update_id']
    try:
        message = body['message']
    except:
        message = body['edited_message']
    message_id = message.get('message_id')
    date = message.get('date')
    text = message.get('text')
    fr = message.get('from')
    chat = message['chat']
    chat_id = chat['id']

    if not text:
        logging.info('no text')
        return

    def reply(msg=None, img=None):
        if msg:
            resp = urllib2.urlopen(BASE_URL + 'sendMessage', urllib.urlencode({
                'chat_id': str(chat_id),
                'text': msg.encode('utf-8'),
                'disable_web_page_preview': 'true',
            })).read()

        else:
            logging.error('no msg or img specified')
            resp = None

        logging.info('send response:')
        logging.info(resp)

    if text.startswith('/'):
        if text == '/start':
            reply('Bot enabled')
            setEnabled(chat_id, True)
        elif text == '/stop':
            reply('Bot disabled')
            setEnabled(chat_id, False)

        else:
            reply('That ain\'t been coded yet.')
```

As I said I'm virgin to Pyhton, and I'd be so thankful if you applied your code to the code that's above this text, instead of giving me ideas(which I wouldn't know how to use them, and get the work done!).

Comment: Did you ever find a way to pass between keyboards?

Answer (score 9):

First, I recommend you to use some module to work with it. Since you're new, the [python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot) could help you.

Well, assuming you will use it, you have two options:

1. You can create a keyboard where the options are commands.

   ```
   def start(bot, update):
       kb = [[telegram.KeyboardButton('/command1')],
             [telegram.KeyboardButton('/command2')]]
       kb_markup = telegram.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(kb)
       bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id,
                        text="your message",
                        reply_markup=kb_markup)

   start_handler = CommandHandler('start', start)
   dispatcher.add_handler(start_handler)
   ```
2. Create text options and use regex to filter them.

   ```
   def start(bot, update):
       kb = [[telegram.KeyboardButton("Option 1")],
             [telegram.KeyboardButton("Option 2")]]
       kb_markup = telegram(chat_id=update.message.chat_id,
                            text="your message",
                            reply_markup=kb_markup)

   start_handler = RegexHandler('some-regex-here', start)
   dispatcher.add_handler(start_handler)
   ```

However, you can't prevent the user from sending any other message he wants. You can only ignore the messages and reply only for commands or keyboard responses.